# PHP - Multidimensional Array Adding

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to add up all values in a multi-dimentional array, based on their item_id. My code:

```
$result = $db->test_order();

/**
 * @array $result   = all menuitems from query
 * @array $newArray = new array without any empty arrays
 */
foreach ($result as $r => $i){
  if (!empty($i['Customizations'])){
    $newArray[] = $i;
  }
}

/**
 * @array $decoded_array = new, multi-dimentional, array with item_id as KEY and qty as VALUE
 */
foreach ($newArray as $r => $i) {
  $a = trim($i['Customizations']);
  $decoded_array[] = json_decode($a, TRUE);
}

var_dump($decoded_array);
```

Output:

```
array (size=18545)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      73 => string '1' (length=1)
      54 => string '1' (length=1)
      63 => string '1' (length=1)
      87 => string '1' (length=1)
      64 => string '1' (length=1)
      34 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      70 => string '1' (length=1)
      45 => string '1' (length=1)
      48 => string '1' (length=1)
      49 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '1' (length=1)
      52 => string '1' (length=1)
      93 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      33 => string '1' (length=1)
      90 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=6)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      27 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '1' (length=1)
      104 => string '1' (length=1)
      52 => string '1' (length=1)
      56 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      108 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=6)
      5 => string '2' (length=1)
      70 => string '3' (length=1)
      8 => string '1' (length=1)
      71 => string '1' (length=1)
      52 => string '3' (length=1)
      6 => string '1' (length=1)
```

The structure of the array is item_ID => QTY_Ordered.

My current step is to iterate through each array and add up all the values for the unique item keys.

Should I join/merge all arrays into one large array or just do it recursively based on key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's only two dimensional, so recursion probably isn't necessary. You can just do a double `foreach` to get the totals.

```
$totals = array();

foreach ($decoded_array as $order) {
    foreach ($order as $item_id => $quantity) {
        if (isset($totals[$item_id])) {
            $totals[$item_id] += $quantity;
        } else {
            $totals[$item_id] = $quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Based on what you said in the question, this may be like what you are already doing, but this is the approach I would use. I don't see that there would be much benefit to joining all the arrays together.

On the other hand, if all these values are coming from your database, I think it would be more efficient to write a query to calculate the totals rather than doing it with PHP.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I wasn't able to get the totals from the DB since the field I'm pulling is stored in json and I couldn't combine the two tables and get the json to add properly so I get the totals in PHP, then attribute ID to name from a different query for reporting.

Comment: You're welcome. Oh yeah, that makes sense. I had already forgotten about the json_decode by the time I had finished writing the first part of the answer.